# loop through a python list that contains dictionaries and lists

Tags: python

How can I loop through / access all the values in the data key from the below list? 1,2,3 etc..

`len(data_list);` returns 2

but

```
for n in data_list:
    print('i')
```

only prints "i" once

something like

```
for i1 in data_list:
    for i2 in i1["rowData"]:
        for i3 in i2["data"]:
            # evaluate the data
```

+++++++++++++

```
 [{
    'groupName': 'groupName1',
    'rowData': [{
        'rowName': 'groupName1_rowNamw',
        'data': {
            'key1': '1',
            'key2': '2',
            'key3': '3'
        }
     }],
     'rowDataLength': 1
 }, {
    'groupName': 'groupName2',
    'rowData': [{
        'rowName': 'groupName2_rowName_a',
        'data': {
            'key1': 'a',
            'key2': 'b',
            'key3': 'c'
        }
   },{
    'rowName': 'groupName2_rowName_b',
        'data': {
            'key1': '4',
            'key2': '5',
            'key3': '6'
        }
    }],
    'rowDataLength': 2
}]
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: _"but [i] only prints once"_. It prints twice on my machine. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: whats wrong with your *something like* code ... that looks like it should basically work (except dictionary keys here are strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print([_d["data"] for  d in l for _d in d["rowData"]])
[{'key3': '3', 'key2': '2', 'key1': '1'}, {'key3': 'c', 'key2': 'b', 'key1': 'a'}, {'key3': '6', 'key2': '5', 'key1': '4'}]
```

If you want the values use .values:

```
print([_d["data"].values() for  d in l for _d in d["rowData"]])
```

In your code  `for i3 in i2["data"]` loops over the keys of the dict.

Answer (score -1):

As others have commented your code looks to do what you want, maybe you just need to print something out to see what you're getting

```
for i1 in data_list:
  print(i1["groupName"])
  for i2 in i1["rowData"]:
    print(i2["rowName"]) 
    for i3 in i2["data"]:
      print(i3, i2["data"][i3])
```